# Android Studio's Deployment Target Options > Emulator > returns `Unknown AVD`

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I'm on Sierra and under `Edit Configuration > Defaults > Android App > Deployment Target Options > Target > Emulator > Prefer AVD >` I see the value `Unknown AVD` [1].

I've tried purging all Android Studio folders (SDKs, etc) on my machine per this [2] post. Prior to the purge, in addition to the issue above (Unknown AVD), there was also the following: `Tools > Android` in main menu was missing and the AVD Manager button in the toolbar was disabled. The purging + new install solved that but did not resolve the Unknown AVD issue. Side note: I can however run the emulator by clicking on the AVD Manager button and starting the emulator up.

Here's how my env variables are configured:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}"
```

Should I also add something like `/.android/avd/` to PATH?

[1]. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFQHq.jpg

[2]. https://gist.github.com/tahmidsadik112/f08356d14a85d898299a